# Can Wayward Children be read in any order?

Tags: suggested-order, wayward-children

Do the books in [Wayward Children](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wayward_Children) have to be read in release order or can you read any one of them first?

Comment: [I tagged the author on Twitter](https://twitter.com/FuzzyDugganSC/status/1586020958023794689)

Answer (score 10):

[According to the author](https://twitter.com/seananmcguire/status/1586021846285430784):

[image: Tweet by Seanan McGuire, text cited below]

> I enormously recommend reading in release order, as the odd numbered books are telling a linear story.

Comment: That was smart!

Comment: *"I also enormously recommend buying all of my books, then buying them all for your friends just in time for Christmas"*